# NodeJS NodeMailer username encoding

Tags: node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I'm using node mailer for sending a couple of emails with a custom smtp transporter & I would like to encode the username & password for my email server. Is there a way of doing it ?

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
            host: 'smtp.example.com',
            port: 25,
            tls: {
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            },
            auth: {
                user: 'no-reply@example.com',
                pass: 'example'
            }
        }))
```

I would like to have something like this :

```
  auth: {
                user: 'bm9tcmVwbHk=',
                pass: 'QVRGGGF0QTE='
            }
```

Thanks !